# Further explanation for the submodule we quotient out by in defining the tensor products of two $R$-modules.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $F^R(M\times N)=R^{\oplus (M\times N)}$ the free $R$-module over $M \times N$.

The tensor product of $M$ and $N$ over $R$ is defined as
$$M \otimes_R N := F^R(M \times N)/K$$
where $K$ the submodule generated by elements of the form
$$(m, r_1n_1+r_2n_2)-r_1(m,n_1)-r_2(m,n_2) \quad \text{ and }\\
(r_1m_1+r_2m_2,n)-r_1(m_1, n)-r_2(m_2,n).$$

---

My question is: **What is $K$?**

I know that it will contain the relations needed so that whenever we have an $R$-bilinear map $f: M\times N \to P$ between $R$-modules, we get a unique $R$-module homomorphism $\bar f: M \otimes_R N \to P$.

But, **beyond the fact that it contains these needed relations, what is $K$? What do the elements look like?**

**If $x,y \in K$, then $rx+y \in K$. Is there something special about $rx+y$?**

Comment: I don't understand what you denote $F^R(M\times N)$. What is $F$?

Comment: @Bernard The free $R$-module over $M \times N$ I suppose i.e. notation for it

Comment: Usually it is denoted $R^ {(M\times N)}$…

Comment: @Bernard $F^R(M\times N)=R^{\oplus (M\times N)}$ the free $R$-module over $M \times N$.

Comment: The correct notation is the one I  mentioned above

Comment: @Bernard I learned that writing $R^A$ for the free $R$ module over $A$ is a slight abuse of notation as the free module is a coproduct and thus formally should be $R^{\oplus A}$. But, since coproducts and products coincide in $R$-$\mathrm{mod}$, then $R^A \cong R^{\oplus A}$.

Comment: Bourbaki debotes the free $R$-module over a set $S$ as $R^{(S)}$ (with parentheses). I stick to this convention.

Comment: @Bernard Any help on the questions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this fully answers your question, but using the notation $m\otimes n$ for the congruence class of $(m,n)$ modulo $K$, $K$ is the `smallest submodule` of $R^{(M\times N)}$ such that the relations
\begin{align}
m\otimes(r_1n_1+r_2n_2) = r_1(m\otimes n_1) + r_2(m\otimes n_2) \\
(r_1m_1+r_2m_2)\otimes n = r_1(m_1\otimes n) + r_2(m_2\otimes n) 
\end{align}
are satisfied for all $m, m_1,m_2\in M$, $\;n,n_1, n_2\in N$, $\;r_1,r_2\in R$ – in other words, such that the canonical map:
\begin{align}
M\times N&\longrightarrow R^{(M\times N)}\Big/ K \\
(m,n)&\longmapsto m\otimes n
\end{align}
is bilinear.